# Begining Bash Scripting in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My teacher randomly dropped bash Script on us the last week of class with no previous use of anything except the bash shell commands on Linux.

I was wondering if someone could give me a small tutorial on how it works by over using the line notes.

the beginning problem is:

Write a bash script called getlines that can output the lines 'A' through 'B' of any given file.

example of the syntax

getline 5 17 "filename"

```
#!/bin/bash
#
a='cat $3 || wc -l'
b=$(($a-$1+1))
c=$(($a-$2+1))
for lines
do
'cat $3 || tail -$b || head -$c'
 done
 echo $lines
```

This is what I have so far, I know the math is off but I'll get to that when I can actually get the syntax up and running can someone just tell me some thing i could fix within the syntax.

Comment: [Bash Beginners Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html)

Comment: Search the web. There are plenty of articles already written for this

Comment: Have a look at the commands `head` and `tail`. Alternatively, pipe the file into a loop and count the lines.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help, and the nice lesson on how the site works ! Sorry if I came across like a lazy kid but I got it to work with:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
a='cat $3 | wc -l'
b=$(($a-$1+1))
c=$(($b-$2-1))
Lines='cat $3 | tail -$b | head -$c'
echo $lines
```

Thanks again guys ! You really did help guide me!